# Problem with solving a system of differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, series-expansion

I am trying to reproduce a result that is part of a derivation of the flow due to a rotating disk.

I have as given this system of differential equations. (In these equations primes indicate differentiation with respect to λ.)

```
λ g''[λ] + h[λ] g'[λ] - h'[λ] g[λ] == 0
λ^3 h'''[λ] + 2 λ^2 h''[λ] + λ^2*h[λ]*h''[λ] + λ*h[λ]*h'[λ] - 
    1/2 λ^2 h'[λ] h'[λ] + 2 g[λ]^2 == 0
```

with the following boundary conditions:

```
c^2 g[l] == 1; g[0] == h[0] == h'[1] == 0; h[1] == 1
```

The system of equations can easily be solved completely by power-series expansions in λ.

[image]

In the end, one should find expressions:

[image]

Here is how I tried to do it in *Mathematica*, but I always get an error:

[image]

Here is how it is solved analytically:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post code, not images

Comment: This DSolve[{eq20==0, eq21==0, c^2*g[1]==1, g[0]==0, h[0]==0, (h'[λ]/.λ->0)==0, h[1]==1}, {g[λ], h[λ]}, λ] (WITHOUT previously defining g[λ] or h[λ] as an infinite sum of subscripted variables) shows how to include the essential third argument to DSolve. But DSolve then just echoes the slightly processed input back, indicating that it can see no way of solving this.

Comment: @Bill, thank you for your comment... do you maybe know a way of how to solve this ?

Comment: @Dr. belisarious, I don't know how to Import Code in traditional form onto a post, I am sorry.

Comment: @DoHe Would doing a numerical solution be acceptable? Instead of an exact symbolic solution? Look into NDSolve. But all variables, other than those being solved for, must have been assigned values, so your c^2*g is going to be a problem. And on putting code into a post, I left click on the blue bracket on the right hand side to highlight one or more cells, then ctrl-C to copy to the clipboard, then swap to the browser to the post window, click to position cursor, ctrl-V to paste, then fix up greek characters be single characters instead of MMA form and do some fixup for spacing. Hope this help

Comment: @m_goldberg Thank you for your edit!

Comment: @Bill Unfortunatly only a symbolic result is acceptant. I included the steps of how to solve it by Hand.

Comment: @DoHe  Does your solution by hand really solve the problem?  It does not take account of the three boundary conditions at `λ = 1`,  Moreover, because the series in (38) and (39) contains only two free parameters, it seems unlikely that it can satisfy those three boundary conditions.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I added an additional comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beginning with the equations,

```
eq = {λ g''[λ] + h[λ] g'[λ] - h'[λ] g[λ] == 0, 
      λ^3 h'''[λ] + 2 λ^2 h''[λ] + λ^2*h[λ]*h''[λ] + λ*h[λ]*h'[λ] - 
          1/2 λ^2 h'[λ] h'[λ] + 2 g[λ]^2 == 0};
```

expand the equations to order `50` and solve for the coefficients of powers of `λ` in terms of the first terms in the series, `a[1]` and `b[1]`.

```
n = 50; var = Flatten[{Array[a[#] &, n, 2], Array[b[#] &, n - 1, 2]}];
(Series[eq, {λ, 0, n}] // Normal) /. {g[0] -> 0, h[0] -> 0} /.
    {Derivative[m_][g][0] -> a[m]*m!, Derivative[m_][h][0] -> b[m]*m!};
Thread[DeleteCases[Flatten[Normal[CoefficientArrays[%, λ]]], 0] == 0];
exp = Simplify[Flatten[Solve[%, var]]];
```

The first few terms are given by

```
(* {a[2] -> 0, 
    a[3] -> -(1/48) a[1] (4 a[1]^2 + b[1]^2), 
    a[4] -> 1/144 a[1] b[1] (4 a[1]^2 + b[1]^2), 
    b[2] -> 1/8 (-4 a[1]^2 - b[1]^2), 
    b[3] -> 1/48 (4 a[1]^2 b[1] + b[1]^3)} *)
```

Next, the values of `g[1]`, `h[1]`, and `h'[1]` are determined simply by summing the expressions for `a[m]`, `b[m]` and `m b[m]`.

```
g1 = Simplify[a[1] + Total[Cases[exp, Rule[a[m_], z_] -> z]]];
h1 = Simplify[b[1] + Total[Cases[exp, Rule[b[m_], z_] -> z]]];
h1p = Simplify[b[1] + Total[Cases[exp, Rule[b[m_], z_] -> m z]]];
```

Finally, obtain the values of `a[1]` and `b[1]` that cause `h1` and `h1p` to satisfy the boundary condition

```
FindRoot[{h1 == 1, h1p == 0}, {a[1], 1}, {b[1], 2}]
(* {a[1] -> 1.53678, b[1] -> 2.36449} *)
```

from which `c` is obtained.

```
c = Sqrt[1/g1 /. %]
(* 0.884474 *)
```

Comment: However I need a symbolic solution

Comment: @DoHe  Your question cites the Benton paper and gives the impression that you wish to obtain that solution using Mathematica.  But, Benton's approach is not analytical, because it uses the equivalent of `FindRoot`.  (Everything else in my answer is analytical in character.)  Why do you believe that a precise analytical solution exists?  Of course, an approximate analytical solution can be obtained by truncating the series solution at around  `n = 4`.  However, even for a truncated series, the resulting polynomial must be solved numerically for high `n`.

Comment: Yes you are right and your solution is very good! No doupt about that. I was just wondering, if one was able to optain the same solution as in equation 38, 39, using Mathematica  ?